# How to iterate over objective function

Tags: python-2.7, gurobi

I want to potentiate certain terms in my objective function.

```
model.addConstr(KW == quicksum(I[t] *(1.05**(-i)) for t in Tst + Z[t] 
* (1.05**(-j)) for t in T)

model.setObjective(KW,GRB.MAXIMIZE)
model.optimize()
```

The variable i should run from 1 to the number of elements in Tst and T 
respectively.
So if t in Tst is [2020,2021,2022], I[2020] gets multiplied by 1.05** 
(-1)
I[2021] by 1.05**(-2) and I[2022] by 1.05**(-3).
Same with Z[t], only that the list of T is larger than Tst.

```
for i in range(1,len(Tst)+1):
    model.addConstr(KW == quicksum(I[t] * (1.05**(-i)))
```

However KW is always 0 then, which it shouldnt be. What am i missing?

Comment: I left out the 2nd part of the obj. fct to make it more simple for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a 2nd dictionary

```
Expo = {}
i=1
for t in T:
    Expo[t] = i
    i = i + 1
```

If I do:

```
model.addConstr(KW == quicksum(I[t] *(1.05**(Expo[t])) for t in Tst + Z[t] 
* (1.05**(Expo[t])) for t in T)

model.setObjective(KW,GRB.MAXIMIZE)
model.optimize()
```

it does what i want. But I dont think its a very good solution :P